Export a Video with Transparency (Video Editor)
I'm trying to render a video with transparency in the video editor. The video renders with transparency using my output settings, but the video is super choppy. It almost appears like its playing at like 10FPS, even though its smooth in the video editor, and is rendered at 60FPS. Here are my render settings:

FFmpeg Video
Color: RGBA
Container: Quick Time
Codec: QT rle / QT Animation

Does anyone know why these setting might make the video look choppy, and how to fix it? Is there a different output setting I can use? Thanks!
Here is a video showing the issue: https://youtu.be/dk8KJ3MBjY8

Is it playing back choppy in Blender or in any video player?

You can check the YouTube link I added to the question, to see what it looks like. Yes, it plays back choppy when I play it with VLC media player, and Celluloid player, as well as Blender, when I add the video back into the video editor to view it.

What's also strange, is that I used to use these settings and they worked just fine. But maybe with the new Blender version of 4.1.1, these settings maybe don't work so well anymore?

I have no idea right now, can't see anything wrong in the settings. Have you tried to set up the exact same video edit in an older version to see if it renders fine there? Or tried making a different video with transparency in 4.1.1? Sorry, just blind guessing because I'm clueless atm.

I just tried it with Blender version 3.6.5, and everything works correctly. So I guess its just an issue with the new Blender version. So if I can't find a fix for it, I will just use 3.6.5 for this.

I guess you should file a bug report in this case, this cannot be the intended behaviour.

are you directly rendering your 3D scene or are you rendering a series of transparent PNG that are in your Video Sequencer?

@moonboots I am rendering a video file, in Blender's video editor. But I have the video moved and scaled, so that one side of the video is transparent.

I'm not sure if it will help if it's a blender version issue, but have you tried using the WebM container and the Codec set to WEBM/VP9 ? That's what I use.
(Also I love your videos, it's rad seeing you on here :D)

Thanks for your help. I tried that, but it doesn't store the transparency in the video. Glad you like my videos!
